# Python error message file name is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.6, defined

i just made the program

```
j = input("choose a file to read")
l = open(j,"r")
e =l.read()
print e
```

ran it, and typed in README.txt, which is a real text file located in the same folder as the program, but every time when I type README.txt, i get an error message saying

```
error FileName: README not defined.
```

I have `python 3.6`. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not actually running that code under `Python 3.6`. The error you are getting is a clear indication that that your `input` is trying to evaluate the input, exactly how Python 2's `input` works. Ensure you are actually in the right Python environment.

Comment: Your statement `print e` without parentheses shows that this is not Python 3.6 code, it is Python 2.x, and that explains your problem with the `input` function. Change that to `raw_input()` and see if that solves your problem. If I add parentheses to the `print` line your code works fine in my Python 3.6.2.

Comment: But the real solution here, is that if you intend to use Python 3.6, then you need to first make sure your code is actually Python 3 compliant, and you are actually running *for* python 3 and not 2.

Answer (score 0):

python 3.x has a bit different with python 2.x

first of all you must use `print (e)` instead of `print e` (if you use python 3.x )then must **close file** ( if you don't this it's not raised error but it's important )  so your code must be :

```
j=input("choose your file  ")


try:
 l=open(j,'r')

 e=l.read()

 print (e)

 l.close()

except:
 print (" no such file ")
```

also you can use function to do this better :

```
def readme(j):
 l=open(j,'r')

 e=l.read()

 l.close()

 print (e) # in python 3.x use print () instead of print 

readme("README.txt")
```